# What tools/techniques are there for understanding the cost of a Gen2 or Gen1 collection

Tags: .net-4.0, garbage-collection, clr, .net-4.5

I know that Gen2 collections especially, (but also occasionally Gen1 collections, which surprised me), are killing my server's performance. I understand that the organization of my objects, and the references between them, can make collection more expensive.  We can re-architect some classes to decouple them, but I'd rather make targeted rather than speculative changes.

Can I find out if some objects in particular are difficult to move?

We using .Net 4.0, and experimenting on 4.5.1 to see if background collection can give us any benefits (so far, it's not clear that it does)

**Edit**

- Individual objects are not especially large, but there are lots of them.
- Objects are separated into disjoint AppDomains, but the coupling within any single AppDomain is high. Within an AppDomain, it seems like everything is reachable from everything else.
- We are not pinning any objects (wonder if that might even help, if that means the GC can skip them quickly).
- We know (or think we know) a lot about object lifetimes. Either they are transient, and should be cleaned up quickly, or they are effectively permanent.

Comment: Are your objects very huge, or are you pinning them? I don't see why any object would be "difficult to move" normally. (Great question otherwise.)

Comment: Also this is worth reading, if you haven't already: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2003/12/04/41281.aspx